# Add a subtotal row as a sumarized items in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a query than i want to do, i want sumarize by two fields, and than on the end of each field it gives me a sumarize, example

**This is what i have,**

[image]

**This is what i want**

[image]

**This is my query code, it will be helpfull to me, the solve of this issue**

```
select  
c.Name                              as Category,
p.Record2                           as Record, 
s.SubTotal                          as [Sub Total],
s.TotalDiscount                     as [Cover],
s.TotalCharges                      as Charges,
s.Total                             as Billed,
s.PaidAmount                        as Paid,
s.DebtAmount                        as Debt,
i.Name as Insurance



 from sales  s 

    inner join status st on    st.StatusId = s.StatusId
     inner join Insurances i  on      i.InsuranceId=  s.InsuranceId 
  inner join categories c on     c.CategoryId =     s.CategoryId
  inner join Customers cu on  cu.CustomerId = s.CustomerId
 inner join people p on p.PersonId=cu.PersonId  
  inner join  CashierDetails cd on cd.CashierDetailId= s.CashierDetailId 
inner join  Cashiers ca on ca.CashierId= cd.CashierId
  inner join Users u on u.UserId= s.UserId

 --and s.InsuranceId=32                  
and  s.SalesDate >= '2019/02/09'     
and  s.SalesDate <= '2019/02/14'     

 order by   s.InsuranceId,s.CategoryId
```

Comment: Look at the ROOLUP command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want grouping sets:

```
with t as (
      <your query here without order by>
     )
select Category, Record,
       sum([Sub Total]) as subtotal, sum(Cover) as cover, 
       sum(Charges) as charges, sum(billed) as billed,
       sum(paid) as paid, sum(debt)
       Insurance
from t
group by grouping sets ( (category, record, insurance), (category, insurance), (insurance) );
```

You can use `coalesce()` or similar logic to replace the `NULL` values with the column values you want.

Comment: I read the oficial documentation, but, without a real xample i didnt understood at all. again thanks